llama-index,uncharted and llama2:7b run locally to generate Index
I wanted to use llama-index locally with ollama and llama3:8b to index utf-8 json file. I dont have a gpu. I use uncharted to convert docs into json. Now If it is not possible to use llama-index locally without GPU I wanted to use hugging face inference API. But I am not certain if it is free.  Can anyone suggest a way?
This is my python code:


    from llama_index.core import Document, SimpleDirectoryReader, VectorStoreIndex
    from llama_index.llms.ollama import Ollama
    import json
    from llama_index.core import Settings
    
    
    # Convert the JSON document into LlamaIndex Document objects
    with open('data/UBER_2019.json', 'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json_doc = json.load(f)
    documents = [Document(text=str(doc)) for doc in json_doc]
    
    # Initialize Ollama with the local LLM
    ollama_llm = Ollama(model="llama3:8b")
    Settings.llm = ollama_llm
    
    # Create the index using the local LLM
    index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)#, llm=ollama_llm)


But i keep getting error that there is no OPENAI key. I wanted to use llama2 so that i dont require OPENAI key
Can anyone suggest what i am doing wrong? Also can i use huggingfaceinference API to do indexing of a local json file for free?

You are not setting the embedding model, so I think Llama Index is defaulting to OpenAI.
You must specify an embedding model that does not require an API key.
You can use Ollama:
from llama_index.embeddings.ollama import OllamaEmbedding

# Using Nomic
Settings.embed_model = OllamaEmbedding(model_name="nomic-embed-text")

# Using Llama
Settings.embed_model = OllamaEmbedding(model_name="llama2")

But there are many options in the documentation like this, this, this

Bad mistake by me.Thank you sir
